# Show / Hide Div When each CheckBoxes Value equals a certain amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `Checkboxes` in `DropDown` i want to use `.each()` to check if One  the `checkBoxes` with `value=2` were `Selected` `Show Div` else `hide` it.

```
$("#TypeAnswerQuestionPage").change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == 2) {

            $('.QuestionScoreMinMax').show(500);
        }
        else {
            $('.QuestionScoreMinMax').hide(500);
        }

    });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the issue you are facing? This is very vague. Please give us some code with your tries and anything specific we can fix.

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: @LloydNicholson I have multiple checkbox selection , if in each one of those checkboxes value were 2 show Div if in those multiple selection checkbox with value 2 unchecked hide div

Comment: I'm confused... you're using checkboxes within a dropdown? Or you're using a dropdown? Do you have any HTML code to add to your answer so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: @HisPowerLevelIsOver9000 You imagine it is a DropDown with MultiSelect option

Comment: Ah ok - dropdown w/ multi-select, got it. Lets see if I can get something for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this fiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/5qwsfepg/2/

In this scenario when you select the second option "Saab" a div that corresponds that choice will be shown. You can of course change and customize as needed but the basic function as follows.

```
$("div").hide();
$('#select_id').click(function() {
  if ($("#select_id option[value=saab]:selected").length > 0) {
    $(".saab-div").show();
  }
});
```

So we first hide all the divs and then only show the one you want when the corresponding item it selected in the dropdown.